# Obtaining HGDP project data in fasta format

Tags: fasta, samtools, human-genome, 1000genomes

I need to obtain sample data from modern humans in fasta format. I just need some megabytes of data from every individual. I actually use a script that obtains the cram file from here (ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk) and then processes it to obtain the fasta file. 
**The problem is that cram files are large, slow to download and slow to process. It takes days to get the samples.
Is there a better way to get these samples in fasta format?**

The script already makes use of samtools to retrieve only the part of the bam file it needs but doesn't help much. Cram files are still gigabytes large for only a few megabytes of data that I need.

I have the same problem with data from the 1000 genomes project.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and clarify a bit? You say "*I just need some megabytes of data from every individual*", what individuals? Everyone in the 1000 genomes project? Then, you say "*I have the same problem with data from the 1000 genomes project.*, what other data are you looking at? Also, what do you _really_ need? Does it _have_ to be from the 1000 genomes project? Do you just need X megabases of sequence from Y individuals and don't care where it comes from? Finally, do you want fasta or fastq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download HGDP data in FASTQ format here: https://www.internationalgenome.org/data-portal/data-collection/hgdp